# If executing even if not met

Tags: arduino

I have this code to switch a relay on if the pressure value changes over a certain amount in a cycle. The relay should only go on if it changes to a negative. This code is very crude so please excuse me, but something bothers me. There is this one is statement which can only be met once, but its contents still executes even when value isn't met.

Check this out, specifically the `ldrStartk`.

```cpp
#include <SFE_BMP180.h>
#include <Wire.h>

SFE_BMP180 pressure;

#define ALTITUDE 1667.0

int ldrValue = 0;
int ldrStart = 0;
bool lstate = 0;
int counter = 0;
int sen = 1;
int ddelay = 30;
static int boolS = 0;
int ldrStartk;

void setup() {
  boolS = 1;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("REBOOT");
  // Initialize the sensor (it is important to get calibration values stored on the device).
  if (pressure.begin())
    Serial.println("BMP180 init success");
  else {
    // Oops, something went wrong, this is usually a connection problem,
    // see the comments at the top of this sketch for the proper connections.
    Serial.println("BMP180 init fail\n\n");
    while (1); // Pause forever.
  }
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  char status;
  double T, P, p0, a;
  status = pressure.startPressure(3);
  if (status != 0) {
    // Wait for the measurement to complete:
    delay(status);
    status = pressure.getPressure(P, T);
    if (status != 0) {
      // Print out the measurement:
      Serial.print("absolute pressure HPA : ");
      Serial.print(P * 10);
      Serial.print(" hpa, ");
      ldrValue = (P * 10);
      Serial.print("ldrValue");
      Serial.print(ldrValue);
      Serial.print(" boolS:");
      Serial.print(boolS);
      if (boolS = 1) {
        ldrStartk = ldrValue ;
        Serial.print("ldrStartk:");
        Serial.print(ldrStartk);
        delay(200);
      }
      if (ldrValue < ldrStart - sen && counter < ddelay && ldrValue <= ldrStartk + sen) {
        boolS = 2;
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        lstate = 1;
        if (lstate = 1)
          counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter >= ddelay) {
          digitalWrite(4, LOW);
          ldrStart = (ldrValue);
        }
      }
      if (ldrValue >= ldrStart - sen) {
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        lstate = 0;
        counter = 0;
        ldrStart = (ldrValue);
      }
      Serial.print(" counter ");
      Serial.print(counter);
      Serial.print(" ldrStart ");
      Serial.println(ldrStart);
      delay(200);
      boolS = 2;
    } else Serial.println("error retrieving pressure measurement\n");
  } else Serial.println("error starting pressure measurement\n");
}
```

And here is the monitor:

```
absolute pressure HPA : 7797.34 hpa, ldrValue7797 boolS:2ldrStartk:7797 counter 0 ldrStart 7797
absolute pressure HPA : 7797.07 hpa, ldrValue7797 boolS:2ldrStartk:7797 counter 0 ldrStart 7797
absolute pressure HPA : 7796.76 hpa, ldrValue7796 boolS:2ldrStartk:7796 counter 0 ldrStart 7796
absolute pressure HPA : 7797.17 hpa, ldrValue7797 boolS:2ldrStartk:7797 counter 0 ldrStart 7797
absolute pressure HPA : 7797.24 hpa, ldrValue7797 boolS:2ldrStartk:7797 counter 0 ldrStart 7797
```

See how it changes even when `if` is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong line of code at line 72.
Your are assigning instead of comparing.

Change

```
if (boolS = 1)
```

to

```
if (boolS == 1)
```

Same situation is on line 61:

```
if (lstate = 1)
```

should be

```
if (lstate == 1)
```

Comment: And the same problem in the 'if (lstate = 1)' statement.